# how to read csv files and save it to multiple tables using Apache spark java api

Tags: java, apache-spark

I need to read csv files having multiple columns and save it to multiple tables using Apache spark java api. Please help if someone can.

Comment: Hi, can you please share what you have done so far? Your question is too vague.

Comment: This has very little information. Is it a CSV to a single dataframe? Is it a CSV to multiple dataframes? Is it multiple CSVs to a single dataframe?

Comment: @Lee Yes I have large file having multiple columns and I need to process it to multiple database table.

Answer (score 3):

In this example, I read from CSV and save some data in Parquet and some data in CSV. The two dataframes are a bit different. You can easily modify to save to a relational database if you need to.

Here is a quick way to load a CSV file in Spark w/ Java:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("CSV to Dataset")
    .master("local")
    .getOrCreate();

// Reads a CSV file with header, called books.csv, stores it in a
// dataframe
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().format("csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .load("data/books.csv");
```

Then to save it, you can do it this way:

```
df
    .write()
    .format("parquet")
    .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
    .save("/tmp/fires_parquet");

Dataset<Row> outputDf = df
    .filter("confidence_level = 'high'")
    .repartition(1);
outputDf
    .write()
    .format("csv")
    .option("header", true)
    .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
    .save("/tmp/high_confidence_fires_csv");
```

I adapted the code from two examples from https://github.com/jgperrin/net.jgp.books.spark.ch01/blob/master/src/main/java/net/jgp/books/spark/ch01/lab100_csv_to_dataframe/CsvToDataframeApp.java (read) and https://github.com/jgperrin/net.jgp.books.spark.ch17/blob/master/src/main/java/net/jgp/books/spark/ch17/lab100_export/ExportWildfiresApp.java write).